# mne-python: Reading and writing edf files leads to runtime error

Tags: python, european-data-format, mne-python

I would like to write an EDF file but haven't found a function in `mne` that would allow me to do so. So I used `pyedflib` instead. But when I try to read my newly created EDF file back using `mne.io.read_raw_edf()`, I get a runtime error:

`RuntimeError: EDF+ Annotations (TAL) channel needs to be parsed completely on loading. You must set preload parameter to True.`

The code that I used for creating EDF files is a demo from `pyedflib`:

https://github.com/holgern/pyedflib/blob/master/demo/writeEDFFile.py

What changes do I need to make either in the write-out or the read-in to be able to use `mne` functions on my EDF file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to preload the data:

```
mne.io.read_raw_edf(preload=True)
```

This is only necessary for the edf files. For .fif files, it is not necessary.